# Cookies not persisted after restarting Chrome on OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, cookies

I'm not sure if this is by design, but whenever I quit Chrome on OSX all of my web account logins require that I re-login. This is a little annoying on gmail as I have 2-step verification setup so I need to login and input the auth code each time I restart the browser.

I have Chrome set to "Allow local data to be set" on cookies so I'm not sure why it's ignoring my cookies after restart.

Answer (score 0):

this may be because you have turned private mode on
in the browser settings it may be set to clear cookies on exit

Comment: Thanks but that's not it, incognito mode is pretty obvious when it's turned on. This is something else

Comment: is your bookmarks still there and history available even after exiting and opened

Comment: check whether your setting clear the cookies evry time it is reopened

Comment: Neither of these are the issue. Bookmarks still available and setting, as called out above, it set to the correct value.